# insert data from dictionary into Mysql database table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have visual studio 2012 windows form c# and Xampp server. I have defined a two dimensional dictionary in which values are stored.
this is  how my dictionary is structured:

society id ->request number-> service category,service type,status

In myphpmyadmin  there is a table which has the same column names ie(society id,request number, service category,service type,status). Only the society id column is filled.the society id values in the table are  same in the dictionary

My problem is: I want to fetch and store the values  of dictionary in the corresponding fields of my database table.

This is my code:

```
  public class Map
{
    public string date_creat { get; set; }
    public string date_Modif { get; set; }
    public string ServiceCgr { get; set; }
    public string ServiceTyp { get; set; }
    public string Req_status { get; set; }

}
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Map>>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Map>>>();
    Map mp=new Map();
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                Req_nber = reader["request_number"].ToString();
                society = reader["pincode"].ToString();



                mp.date_creat = reader["date_created"].ToString();
                mp.date_Modif = reader["date_modified"].ToString();
                mp.ServiceCgr = reader["service_category"].ToString();
                mp.ServiceTyp = reader["service_type"].ToString();
                mp.Req_status = reader["request_status"].ToString();

                //if pincode or society already exists
                if (dic.ContainsKey(society)) //2nd if
                {
                    //if request number already exists
                    if (dic[society].ContainsKey(Req_nber))
                    {
                        //add records
                        dic[society][Req_nber].Add(mp);
                    }

                    //else part
                    else // if we get a new request number
                    {
                        //rnumber is added and value part is newed up
                        dic[society].Add(Req_nber, new List<Map>());
                        //record is added into list
                        dic[society][Req_nber].Add(mp);
                    }
                }//end 2nd if

                else//if we get a new society
                {
                    //pcode is added and value part is newed up
                    dic.Add(society, new Dictionary<string, List<Map>>());
                    //rnumber is added and value part is newed up
                    dic[society].Add(Req_nber, new List<Map>());
                    //record is added into list
                    dic[society][Req_nber].Add(mp);
                }

            }//end while
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? You could either use sql insert statements with a `DbCommand`, parameters and loop through your map - or try to solve the problem with sql only, filling the map directly by using a `INSERT INTO` statement or something alike... But where is the problem? What does not work for you`?

Comment: how to insert data from a two dimensional dictionary into mysql database table?